# Import terraform AWS VPC subnet having CIDR in resource name

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, amazon-vpc, terraform0.12+

I need to import AWS VPC subnets into terraform using import command. When I run `terraform plan` command I get below output

```
module.test-vpc.aws_subnet.play["10.76.175.0/24"]
```

how do I import this resource as it contains this ["10.76.175.0/24"] cidr block. Below are the command I tried which is failing with this error `Error: Invalid number literal`

```
terraform import module.test-vpc.aws_subnet.play[10.76.175.0/24] sub-xyz
```

I tired below commands that got successful import but unable to recognise resources when I run `terraform plan` again.

```
terraform import module.test-vpc.aws_subnet.play sub-xyz
terraform import module.test-vpc.aws_subnet.play[0] sub-xyz
```

Comment: Have you actually tried searching for it in the documentation prior to asking the question: https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/cli/commands/import#example-import-into-resource-configured-with-for_each?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The module probably use a for_each condition, so the right command should be

```
terraform import module.test-vpc.aws_subnet.play["10.76.175.0/24"] sub-xyz
```

or

```
terraform import 'module.test-vpc.aws_subnet.play["10.76.175.0/24"]' sub-xyz
```

with quotes. Because you reference a resource by the key.

It's also possible to reference the resources by a number that represent the order in the map but is not recommended because it's hard to understand if you are doing the right import.

So, doing the commands

```
terraform import module.test-vpc.aws_subnet.play sub-xyz
terraform import module.test-vpc.aws_subnet.play[0] sub-xyz
```

you already imported the resources so you don't see that in plan anymore. You can remove the resource from the state by

```
terraform state rm module.test-vpc.aws_subnet.play[0]
```

and re-import the resource

Comment: The first solution you provided was already not working but I tried second solution with quotes that is also giving following error : 'The given key does not identify an element in this collection value.'

Comment: Now when you do a plan you see again `module.test-vpc.aws_subnet.play["10.76.175.0/24"]` ?
Are you sure it's the correct resource address?

Comment: Your second solution worked for one subnet, for others it is giving a new error which I will try to resolve